# Using Ansible wait_for module to check whether a port is released

Tags: ansible

I would like to check whether the port 8301 is in use (such as it is not released by last process) before bringing up a service which uses the same port:

```
[dujas@centos8-8 bin]$ netstat -tlnp | grep 8301
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 192.168.209.148:8301    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      41456/consul
```

till:

```
[dujas@centos8-8 bin]$ netstat -tlnp | grep 8301
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

I am aware that wait_for module should help me on this, but I did not make it after several tries, could anyone give me some clues in this situation? Well, I could use "retries..until.." achieve this though.

Thanks.

Comment: `but I did not make it after several tries` <= please include those tries or at least the most advanced one in the question with the result as is and the one you actually expect.

Answer (score 0):

There is clear explanation in [documentation of **wait_for module** for **state** parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html#parameter-state):

> **stopped** will check that it is closed

so below command line example of how to check that port 8080 is closed, and fail if it wasn't closed for 15 seconds:

```
ansible -m wait_for --args="port=8080 state=stopped timeout=15" localhost
```

or in form of playbook:

```
- hosts: webserver
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.wait_for:
        port: 8080
        state: stopped
        timeout: 15
```

Comment: Thanks @artild for the reply. Actually I tried this way but it did not work, port 8301 in my case will not be released right away after the   process is terminated, finally I use retries+until instead. Thanks for your reply.